# time-based when configure an index pattern not working

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Hi!

I have an issue about set a date field as `time-based` when I configure my index pattern. When I choose my date filed on the timefield name, I cannot Vizualise any data on the `Discover` part.

However, when I uncheck the box named `Index contains time-based events`, all data appears:

[image: Screenshot]

Maybe I forgot something during my mapping ? There is the mapping I've set for this index:

```
"index_test" : {
    "mappings": {
    "tr": {
        "_source": {
            "enabled":true
        },
        "properties" : {
            "id" : { "type" : "integer" },
            "volume" : { "type" : "integer" },
            "high" : { "type" : "float" },
            "low" : { "type" : "float" },
            "timestamp" : { "type" : "date", "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" }
        }
    }
    }'
}
```

I am currently try to use `timelion` also, and it seems to not found any data to show. I think it cannot because of this `time-based` unchecked... Any idea about how set this timestamp as `time-based` without loose the data access on the `Discover` part ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple question with simple answer... I just forgot to set the timepicker in the Right-top of the Discover part to show past data:

[image: Screen]